# Refresh listview/display newly added data to listview android

Tags: android, sqlite, listview

I'm new to Android Sqlite DB Dev't so I need your help guys. I was able to do the basic CRUD operations. Now I want to know how to refresh the listview to display the newly added data. I've looked into adapter.notifyDataSetChanged but I wonder why it's not working for me. Here's what I've tried so far

```
   private void initControls() {

    SearchAuto = (AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteTextView1);
    String[] SearchItems = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.DogSearch);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.searchitems,SearchItems);
    SearchAuto.setAdapter(adapter);
    SearchAuto.setThreshold(0);

    search = (Button) findViewById (R.id.handle);
    search.setOnClickListener(this);
    lv = (ListView) findViewById (R.id.lv);

    values = dbHelper.getAllAnimals(ANIMALTYPE);
    for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
        lvAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, values);
        lv.setAdapter(lvAdapter);
    }

    // TODO onItemClick
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id)
         {
            String strDog = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();

            Intent i = new Intent(DogClass.this, Dogs.class);
            i.putExtra("dog_name", strDog);
            startActivity(i);    
            finish();
         }
    });

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.addanimal, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    // get prompt_addprayer.xml view
    LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(this);
    View promptsView = li.inflate(R.layout.prompt_addanimal, null);

    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = 
            new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

    // set prompts.xml to alertdialog builder
    alertDialogBuilder.setView(promptsView);

    final EditText etBreed = (EditText) promptsView
            .findViewById(R.id.etBreed);

    final EditText etDescription = (EditText) promptsView
            .findViewById(R.id.etDescription);

    final EditText etDiet = (EditText) promptsView
            .findViewById(R.id.etDiet);

    final EditText etShelter = (EditText) promptsView
            .findViewById(R.id.etShelter);

    final EditText etHygiene = (EditText) promptsView
            .findViewById(R.id.etHygiene);

    final EditText etMedication = (EditText) promptsView
            .findViewById(R.id.etMedication);

    // set dialog message
    alertDialogBuilder
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setPositiveButton("OK",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(
                                DialogInterface dialog,
                                int id) {

                            String strAnimalType = ANIMALTYPE;
                            String strBreed = etBreed.getText().toString();
                            String strDesc = etDescription.getText().toString();
                            String strDiet = etDiet.getText().toString();
                            String strShelter = etShelter.getText().toString();
                            String strHygiene = etHygiene.getText().toString();
                            String strMedication = etMedication.getText().toString();

                                dbHelper.addAnimalInfo(strAnimalType, strDesc, 
                                        strDiet, strShelter, strHygiene, strMedication, strBreed);
                                Toast.makeText(DogClass.this, "Data has been added successfully!",
                                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                lvAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        }

                    })
            .setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(
                                DialogInterface dialog,
                                int id) {
                            dialog.cancel();
                        }
                    });

    // create alert dialog
    AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
    // show it
    alertDialog.show();
    return true;



}
```

Any ideas? I really need to get this working. Thanks

Comment: What this loop for: for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++)!remove it. and keep what inside it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dbHelper.addAnimalInfo(strAnimalType, strDesc, strDiet, strShelter, strHygiene, strMedication, strBreed);
Toast.makeText(DogClass.this, "Data has been added successfully!",
                                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

lvAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

This is where you lacked. What you did is, you just inserted data into database, still you are remaining to bring data from database and bind it with adapter, and after that you may call `notifyDataSetChanged();`, and you'll achieve what you want...

Try this:

```
dbHelper.addAnimalInfo(strAnimalType, strDesc, strDiet, strShelter, strHygiene, strMedication, strBreed);
    Toast.makeText(DogClass.this, "Data has been added successfully!",
                                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
values = dbHelper.getAllAnimals(ANIMALTYPE);
lvAdapter.clear();
lvAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, values);

    lvAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

**Note:** you should not write this way. Your code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
        lvAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, values);
        lv.setAdapter(lvAdapter);
    }
```

If your `getAllAnimals()` method is returning an arrayList then you simply need to:

```
lvAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, values);
        lv.setAdapter(lvAdapter);
```

The last argument of your ArrayAdapter constructor needs `List<Item>` to be passed. And then just call `setAdapter(adapter)` of `ListView`.

For more clarification, refer this SO link: [notifyDataSetChanged example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3669325/notifydatasetchanged-example)
http://androidadapternotifiydatasetchanged.blogspot.in